# closure verification override default mocking

Tags: spock

I have a method looks like this:

```
public void save(DbSession session,Wrappe wrapper,Wrappe wrappe){
      //...other logic

      //save wrapper
      wrapper=(Wrapper)session.save(wrapper)

      //set wrapper's id into wrappee
      wrappee.setWrapperId(wrapper.getId());

      //save wrappee
      session.save(wrappee);
}
```

and test code looks like this:

```
    given:      
    session.save(_) >> wrapperWithGeneratedId

    when:
    obj.save(session,wrapper,wrappee)

    then:"wrapper got saved"
    1*session.save(_) >> {Wrapper save ->
         diffs(wrapper,saved)==null
    }
    and:"wrappee"
    1*session.save(_) >> {Wrappe saved ->
        diffs(wrappee,saved)==null
    }
```

These test code will give an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.company.model.Wrapper
```

If commented verification closure in "then" section,test will pass,so I guess this section

```
1*session.save(_) >> {Wrapper save ->
         diffs(wrapper,saved)==null
}
```

overrode this mocking:

```
session.save(_) >> wrapperWithGeneratedId
```

Is any way do both correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st. 'and' is syntactic sugar. It's just a way to visually separate code within the same block. Your last two mocks are effectively the same (although since you're testing behaviorally it will still verify that save is called twice.)

2nd. Assuming you want to verify that`diffs(wrapper,saved)==null`, that won't currently happen because it's not a 'base level' evaluation. Anything within then/where/closures/etc needs to be prepended with 'assert ' if you want to evaluate it.

3rd. A then block is scoped to its when block and can override existing mocks; your assumption that your mock was being overwritten is correct.

4th. Is there any reason you don't just include your return value alongside your evaluation?

```
2 * session.save(_) >> {Wrapper save ->
     diffs(wrapper,saved)==null
     return wrapperWithGeneratedId
}
```

5th. Your error is due to your mock returning a boolean (your assertion logic) which Groovy then tries (and fails) to parse into a Wrapper. My assumption for why this is happening is that .save() has a return type of Wrapper.  To fix that you will either need to create a boolean constructor for Wrapper, or change your mock to return something Groovy can turn into a Wrapper (how-to in point 4)

[Official Stub/Mock/Spy documentation (quite good, worth a read)](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html)